# Extracting Text from Span Tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, zillow

I am trying to extract the estimated monthly cost of "$1,773" from this url:

https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/4651-Genoa-St-Denver-CO-80249/13274183_zpid/

[image]

Upon inspecting that part of the page, I see this data:

```
<div class="sc-qWfCM cdZDcW">
   <span class="Text-c11n-8-48-0__sc-aiai24-0 dQezUG">Estimated monthly cost</span>
   <span class="Text-c11n-8-48-0__sc-aiai24-0 jLucLe">$1,773</span></div>
```

To extract $1,773, I have tried this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/4651-Genoa-St-Denver-CO-80249/13274183_zpid/'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html")

print(soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'Text-c11n-8-48-0__sc-aiai24-0 jLucLe'}))
```

This returns a list of three elements, with no mention of $1,773.

```
[<span class="Text-c11n-8-48-0__sc-aiai24-0 jLucLe">$463,300</span>, 
<span class="Text-c11n-8-48-0__sc-aiai24-0 jLucLe">$1,438</span>, 
<span class="Text-c11n-8-48-0__sc-aiai24-0 jLucLe">$2,300<!-- -->/mo</span>]
```

Can someone please explain how to return $1,773?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to find the first parent element.
for example:

```
parent_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'sc-fzqBZW bzsmsC'})
result = parent_div.findAll('span', {'class': 'Text-c11n-8-48-0__sc-aiai24-0 jLucLe'})
```

Comment: Thanks! Some edits to your first code line does return the cost, but its value is not $1773 (it giving an output of $1438 even though this value is not present in the URL shared). 

"soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'sc-qWfCM cdZDcW'})[0].contents[1].contents[0]".

I have updated my question with reproducible code.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but parent_div is returning None. Also, I have updated the question with a snapshot of the monthly cost of "$1773" from the url shared for reference.

Comment: I did try your code. but I get error with robot page.

Comment: do you have $kype? live:.cid.626f9a797d9b6ef9

Comment: I am waiting for your contact. I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

While parsing a web page we need to separate components of the page in the way they are rendered. There are components that are statically or dynamically rendered. The dynamic content also takes some time to load, as the page calls for backend API of some sort.

[Read more here](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/web-scraping-using-beautiful-soup-and-selenium-for-dynamic-page-2f8ad15efe25)

I tried parsing your page using Selenium ChromeDriver

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/4651-Genoa-St-Denver-CO-80249/13274183_zpid/")
time.sleep(3)
time.sleep(3)
el = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='Text-c11n-8-48-0__sc-aiai24-0 jLucLe']")

for e in el:
    print(e.text)

time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()

#OUTPUT
$463,300
$1,773
$2,300/mo
```